# How to add an authentication header in sencha architect, using the store option?

Tags: ajax, extjs, touch

I'm trying to add an authentication header to the sencha architect Store, the api that I'm consuming is an api with sanctum authentication.
In the components I made a POST request placing the auth token and everything went well, my error is happening in the following part within the Store:
There is a Headers option, and I imagine that would be where I put 'Authorizathion' and then the access token, for example: 'Authorizathion': Bearer 1|TokenTeste. However, in its composition, it understands the entire line as a string, and not an array that I'm passing parameters and values into, would anyone know how to pass this parameter correctly? Or would there be another viable option for such functionality?
I am attaching a corresponding image of this, to exemplify how the Headers option is only as a string.

I tried adding an authentication token to the headers option in the sencha architect store.
However, it does not open the array option with parameters and values, just a single string.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oQT6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can globally modify each ajax request header by adding this code fragment into you app.controller *init* function for example. I'dont have Sencha architect but I suppose you could create app controller in "Applications/Controllers" tree item.

```
Ext.Ajax.setWithCredentials(true);
Ext.Ajax.on({
    beforerequest: function(conn, options) {
        options.headers = options.headers || {};
        options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ASDFASDFQWERQ....WERh';
        // Dont forget to hide hash to variable
    },
```

});